# Where can I find the source code of Wikipedia / Wiktionary templates?

Tags: wikipedia

Wikipedia and its sister sites make heavy use of templates. I want to find the source code behind those templates, i.e. the code that renders the HTML from a given template reference.

Looking [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/find/master), I found a few files which seem to deal with templates, but I could not find any results when looking for a specific one. For example, the template `{es-conj}`, which renders a conjugation table for a given Spanish verb, did not show up in the search list.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the source code of the template is saved as plain-text in the template's wiki page itself. To see the source code of the template `{es-conj}`, just go to its page and click *Edit*:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:es-conj

Comment: For most templates, that shows the wiki-code, not the HTML, generated by the templates.  To get the generated HTML you'd need to look into the source code of Mediawiki itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the templates involved in generating the page via page information, linked from the sidebar on desktop skins ([e.g.](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=absconder&action=info)). There's an edit / view source link for each.

You can also add `?action=raw&templates=expand` to the URL of a page to see the page source after all templates have been processed.